# Ghosts on Torus worldsheet

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, brst, ghosts

Why after the expansion, only 0-mode of bc-ghost contributes to the 4-points ghost function on a torus worldsheet?

$$<c(z_1)b(z_2)\tilde{c}(\bar{z}_3)\tilde{b}(\bar{z}_4)>_{T^2} ~\longrightarrow~ <c_0 b_0 \tilde{c}_0 \tilde{b}_0>$$

Answer (score 3):

On the torus there are two real moduli $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, and two conformal Killing vectors corresponding to translations. This means that you need two insertions of $b$ and two insertions of $c$ in order to saturate the zero mode path integral.

Comment: If it's possible, could you please show me a (rigorous) prove for that? Thank you!

Comment: It would be hard to explain it better than chapter 5 of Polchinski. I would recommend that to you.